# Authorize swagger UI using firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, openapi, swagger-ui

I'm currently hosting swagger UI with the following security scheme:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    firebase:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: ''
          scopes: {}
```

However, when I use the Authorize button in the interface, I get a popup to enter a client ID. When I enter any value, it just reloads the page. How can I make this authorize button work so I can make API calls from within the interface?